# How to connect ngrok with bot emulator?

Tags: c#, chatbot, ngrok

I have developed a chatbot in C# and hosted it on our local server. When I'm trying to connect it remotely with **ngrok**. I get below error:

> Failed to spawn ngrok{"error_code":104,"status_code":503,"msg":"ngrok
> is not yet ready to start tunnels","details":{"err":"a successful
> ngrok tunnel session has not yet been established"}} [12:25:59]Error:
> The bot is remote, but the service URL is localhost. Without tunneling
> software you will not receive replies.

Comment: this may help you https://www.sitepoint.com/use-ngrok-test-local-site/

Comment: Who is calling your chatbot? Are you using a cloud platform?

Comment: BOT emulator is using for chatbot calling. Chat BOT is hosted on local server. not using cloud platform.

Answer (score 0):

try npm upgrade. i think it may fix the problem